# Reporting java exceptions in jira automaticly

Tags: java, exception, reporting, jira

I'm developing web application using Spring roo (mvc), this application is the ERP system. I plan to use Jira as my issues reporting system.

My question is: if is there any solution that will help me report exceptions thrown in my web application in jira automatically?

I thought about creating some script that will be scanning logs and creating issues in jira. What do you think about it?

Comment: Not much, honestly. If your application runs mad you may get tons of exceptions for a single problem (or incident, maybe not even a problem) and that would result in tons of individual jira issues, that you'd resolve one by one

Comment: I'd use a separate monitoring system and have that create JIRA issues. That's one way to not have many (many) duplicate issues in JIRA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem you can use LogDigger library.

Here you've got an article, which has showed up lately, where it is decribed how to integrate LoggDigger with Zendesk. There is also presented how to ignore some of exceptions and how to prevent duplicates on helpdesk systems. Analogously, you can integrate LogDigger with Jira using its REST API.

http://mobeelizer.com/blog/2013/01/how-to-integrate-logdigger-with-zendesk-quick-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to create tickets in jira is [to send a simple email](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email). You can also use the [Rest API](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/) (thanks to aphex).

In Spring Web MVC you can use an [ExceptionHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) to "do something" when an exception occurres. You can also use a `HandlerExceptionResolver` to globally handle all exceptions in the same way.

Maybe [this](http://steveliles.github.com/configuring_global_exception_handling_in_spring_mvc.html) article can help you with handling exceptions

However, as Andreas pointed out in the comments you should make sure that you do not report the same error multiple times. This can easily result in tons of jira tickets.

Comment: I would add to your answer, that you can use also the REST API http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/